# Programmatically remove a listener added using FXML?

Tags: listener, javafx-2, actionlistener, fxml

I am adding a listener using FXML:

```
<RadioButton onAction="#onSelectionChanged" />
```

Now I need to temporarily disable this listener programmatically.

Now I could set some boolean variable "listenerDisabled" and check this variable in the listener, but I want a way to disable a listener without changing it - so I want to remove it.

The problem here is: How do I reference the listener in my code, so I can use the following?

```
RadioButton.selectedProperty().removeListener(<what to place here?>)
```

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Related to the issue : http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-12528

Comment: Can you attach a listener in the code too? =)

Answer (score 3):

Add an fx:id specification to your fxml:

```
<RadioButton fx:id="myRadio" onAction="#onSelectionChanged" />
```

In the corresponding controller for the fxml, use the `@FXML` notation to have the `FXMLLoader` inject a reference to the radio button into your controller:

```
@FXML RadioButton myRadio;
```

To get a reference to the listener, invoke `getOnAction`:

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> myRadioActionEvent = myRadio.getOnAction();
```

To remove the listener, use `setOnAction`:

```
myRadio.setOnAction(null);
```

To add the listener back again, use `setOnAction` again:

```
myRadio.setOnAction(myRadioActionEvent);
```

I didn't try any of the above, but I don't see why it would not work.

Comment: yes, this should work. I was only looking to somehow reference the created handler directly, but sometimes the solutions are just too easy :)

Comment: Is there no way to create the `onAction()` programmatically? Otherwise I'll have to create and radiobutton and make it invisible just to set an action to it, because I'm creating several different radiobuttons on a combobox action. At first there isn't any in the screen.